# Adding a title to a JavaFX ContextMenu

Tags: javafx

Is it possible to add a title to a JavaFX `TableView` `ContextMenu`?

For now, I have added a `MenuItem` which I have marked disabled (via `menuTitle.setDisable(true)`), but that is rendered with some style settings (opacity) that I havent figured out how to override.

Code sample -

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithContextMenu extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(column("Item", Item::nameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Value", Item::valueProperty));

        BooleanProperty globalSelection = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        table.setRowFactory(t -> {
            TableRow<Item> row = new TableRow<>();
            ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem menuTitle = new MenuItem("Menu Title");
            menuTitle.setDisable(true);

            MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Do something else");
            item2.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Do something else with " + row.getItem().getName()));

            CheckMenuItem item3 = new CheckMenuItem("Global selection");
            item3.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(globalSelection);

            contextMenu.getItems().addAll(menuTitle, item2, new SeparatorMenuItem(), item3);

            row.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isEmpty) -> {
                if (isEmpty) {
                    row.setContextMenu(null);
                } else {
                    row.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
                }
            });
            return row ;
        });

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 25).mapToObj(i -> new Item("Item "+i, i)).forEach(table.getItems()::add);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
The solution posted below, works for this example. However, when dealing with multiple FXML, it doesnt work unless I clear out the style classes and then apply the custom style. I have posted my working code [here](https://gist.github.com/darthninja1/7e9b086359808807eb7c) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opacity of a disabled `MenuItem`is specified in the CSS style class `menu-item:disabled`. To completely get rid of the opacity you also need to override the style class for the `Label` inside that disabled `MenuItem` named `menu-item:disabled .label`. Just override that style by specifying it yourself in your own css file:

Example:

```
.menu-item:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}

.menu-item:disabled .label {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}
```

You probably don't want other disabled menu items that isn't supposed to be a title to have the same style though. In this case you could just add a style class to the title `MenuItem`:

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem titleItem = new MenuItem("Title");
titleItem.setDisable(true);
titleItem.getStyleClass().add("context-menu-title");
```

And the css would then be:

```
.context-menu-title:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}

.context-menu-title:disabled .label {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}
```

**Edit:** You probably don't want the title to have the same `:hover` style as the rest of the menu items either. This could be fixed by setting `:disabled:hover` for the title `MenuItem`. E.g:

```
.context-menu-title:disabled:hover {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.context-menu-title:disabled:hover .label {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

Comment: So this worked in the standalone example I pasted above. However I was unable to get it working in a more complex program where I have multiple FXML files (each having its own css). From the debugger, I have confirmed that the row has 2 style classes applied - "menu-item" and "context-menu-title". 

The only way I got this working was by removing the classes via `row.getStyleClass().clear()` and then only adding the "context-menu-title". However, a side effect of that was I lose the other style settings that were from the "menu-item" class. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you describe the problem you're having? I'm not familiar with using FXML so I'll have trouble troubleshooting your sample code. Anyway, you could just copy the CSS properties for `menu-item` from the modena CSS file to your own `context-menu-title`. How to locate the file is described [here](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part4/).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a title to a [ContextMenu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html).

ContextMenu are extended from [PopupWindow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/PopupWindow.html) which do not allow window decoration or title bar.

From the docs :

> A PopupWindow is a secondary window which has no window decorations or title bar. It doesn't show up in the OS as a top-level window. It is typically used for tool tip like notification, drop down boxes, menus, and so forth.